# Merge multiple files after process into one data frame and assign file name to each colname

Tags: r

I have a list of file and I wrote a function to process each file and return two columns ("name" and "value").

```
file_list <- list.files(pattern=".txt")
sample_name <- sub (".*?lvl.(.*?).txt","\\1",file_list)

for (i in 1:length(file_list)){
 x<- cleanMyData(file_list[i]) # this function returns a two column data 
 #then I want to merge all these processed data into one dataframe. Merge all "value" column based on the "name" column 
 # at the same time I want to put the file name in the corresponding column name. I already process the file name and put them into sample_name
}
```

To be more clear, here is my processed data for example:

```
file: apple.txt 
name value
A     12
B     13
C     14

file: pear.txt
name value
A     15
B     14
C     20
D     21
```

Expect output:

```
  Apple Pear
A   12   15
B   13   14
C   14   20
```

Comment: You _could_ just `cbind` the two data frames, but that would assume that the rows line up exactly right.  The other option would be to `merge()` the two data frames on the `name` column.

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
fns <- c("apple.txt", "pear.txt")
(df <- 
Reduce(function(...) merge(..., all=F), 
       lapply(
         seq(fns), function(x) {
           read.table(fns[x], 
                      header=TRUE, 
                      col.names = c("name", 
                                    tools::file_path_sans_ext(fns)[x]))
         })
)
)
#   name     apple     pear
# 1    A        12       15
# 2    B        13       14
# 3    C        14       20
```

To capitalize the first characters, you could use something like

```
sub("\\b(\\w)", "\\U\\1", fns, perl=TRUE)
```

(see `?sub`)

To get rid of the `name` column, you could use `subset(df, select = -name)`.